# How to drag rigid bodies with a rigged mesh?

Tags: animation, rigging, rigid-body-simulation

I started the animation of my project and I want to carry stones from one place to another. I am using rigid bodies on the stones so each one of them is an individual object. Here in the first picture are they in the initial position. 
[image]

But when I move the loader in a diferent frame the stones stay in the initial position like in picture 2
[image]

How can I move these stones with my rigged mesh (front end Loader)?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you using BGE?

Comment: This is blender cycles. This is what I did: in the first 50 frames I let the rocks fall on the truck and the loader by simply animating with rigid bodies as there are hundred stones and I didn't wanted to place them one by one. Then I made the animation of the loader. I thought the stones will move with the loader but nope... I don't have a clue what to do right now.

Comment: Could you provide your file on blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to be able to have a look and help you

Comment: Sorry I don't want to post the file. But thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rigid body objects only interact with other rigid body objects. To make the loader bucket "pick up" the rocks it will need to have rigid body enabled. As you are using an animation to move the bucket you should enable the animated option. You also need to set the collision shape to mesh so that the bucket will be hollow to allow the rocks inside it.

[image: rigid body settings]

[image: example animation]

You will also want to use similar settings for the truck.

Comment: Hi Sambler.Thanks for your answer. I did what you say but is not working for me. I will post the pictures on the post. They just move until they touch the bucket and then they (stones) stop movin while the bucket keep playing the animation alone

Comment: I don't know if it is because when I am animating the bucket I don't select the bucket but only the armature which is in pose mode and the rocks works maybe only in object mode. Is there maybe a way to apply the armature position to the loader in object mode, so that the stones maybe get the movements applied too?

Comment: I selected the deforming option and  put friction on 1 and made the animation a little slower and is working a little better although some of the stone still falling to the floor. Picture on the post

Comment: Ok, I got it. The stones have to be very big to keep the movement with the truck. Thanks Sambler and Tak.